# Unable to write complex generic definition for a class

Tags: java, generics, assertj

I am trying to write assert class for my custom class

```
public class ChangeCollector<T> 
   extends ArrayList<ChangeEntry<T>>
```

and I am writing

```
public class ChangeCollectorAssert
   <T, EA extends AbstractAssert<EA, ChangeEntry<T>>> 
      extends AbstractListAssert
         <ChangeCollectorAssert<T, EA>, ChangeCollector<T>, ChangeEntry<T>, EA>
```

and it swears

```
Type parameter 'ChangeCollector' is not within its bound; 
should implement 'java.util.List<? extends ChangeEntry<T>>'
```

but looks like it does implement `List`, doesn't it?

Isn't `ArrayList<ChangeEntry<T>>` assignable to `List<? extends ChangeEntry<T>>`?

**UPDATE**

I wrote the following code:

```
private static <T> void test01() {
      List<? extends T> list1;
      ChangeCollector<T> list2 = new ChangeCollector<T>();

      list1 = list2; // ok!
   }
```

<s>and it compiles ok</s>

No, it didn't compile ok. I confused compiler and checker. But what is the problem with that conversion?

Comment: Have a look here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html

Comment: Looks known. Where to look specifically?

Comment: *but looks like it does implement List, doesn't it?*, the error says **explicitly** what it need to implement, and that is not `List` it is `java.util.List<? extends ChangeEntry<T>>` there is a big difference between that and `ArrayList<ChangeEntry<T>>` because that is not how it works.

Comment: Shouldn't `ChangeCollector<ChangeEntry<T>>` be `ChangeCollector<T>`? `ChangeCollector<ChangeEntry<T>>` extends `ArrayList<ChangeEntry<ChangeEntry<T>>>`.

Comment: This could fix it: `public class ChangeCollector<T extends ChangeEntry<?>> extends ArrayList<T> {`